# Как использовать in в QueryBuilder?

Tags: postgresql, doctrine, silex

Никак не выходит сделать in условие для запроса в таблицу PostgreSQL с полем service (enum). Значения указываю существующие, в этом проблемы нет. Я пытался делать implode, но queryBuilder экранирует строку целиком, я пытался передать массив, но получаю array to string conversion и параметр Array вместо 'ACTIVE', 'ANOTHER'. Как правильно в queryBuilder сделать условие in для enum?

```php
public function query()
{
    return $this->db()->createQueryBuilder();
}


public function getActiveSubscriberServices($msisdn)
    {
        $result = $this->query()
                ->select('id')
                ->from('subscriber.service')
                ->where('state in (?)')
                ->setParameter(0, [
                        'ACTIVE',
                        'ANOTHER',
                ])
                ->execute();
        return $result->fetchAll();
    }
```

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT id FROM subscriber.service WHERE (state in (?))' with params [[\"ACTIVE\",\"ANOTHER\"]]:\n\nSQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input value for enum subscriber.service_state: \"Array\"

Пробую сделать вот так

```php
->where($this->query()->expr()->in('state', [
    'ACTIVE',
    'ANOTHER',
]))
```

И получаю такой in: `IN (ACTIVE, ANOTHER)`, что не работает, потому что значения внутри in должны быть экранированы.

Сейчас использую код, приведенный ниже, но это не гибко и немного костыльно.

```php
$services = [Service::STATE_ACTIVE, Service::STATE_ACTIVATING];

$result = $this->query()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('subscriber.service')
        ->where($this->query()->expr()->in('state',
            array_map(function($item) {
                return '?';
            }, array_keys($services))))
        ->setParameters($services)
        ->andWhere('msisdn = ?')
        ->setParameter(count($services), $msisdn)
        ->execute();
return $result->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать примерно вот такой код:

```
$services = [Service::STATE_ACTIVE, Service::STATE_ACTIVATING];

$result = $this->query()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('subscriber.service')
        ->where('state in (:services)')
        ->setParameter('services', $services, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);         
        ->andWhere('msisdn = ?')
        ->setParameter(count($services), $msisdn)
        ->execute();
return $result->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Конкретно этот пример работать не будет, но само условие у меня сработало. Это лучший вариант, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Под рукой нет средств для проверки, овтет идет по [документации](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html):

> // Example - $qb->expr()->in('u.id', array(1, 2, 3))
>   // Make sure that you do NOT use something similar to $qb->expr()->in('value', array('stringvalue')) as this will cause Doctrine to throw an Exception.
>   // Instead, use $qb->expr()->in('value', array('?1')) and bind your parameter to ?1 (see section above)

```
public function getActiveSubscriberServices($msisdn)
{
    $result = $this->query()
            ->select('id')
            ->from('subscriber.service')
            ->where($this->query()->expr()->in('state', [
                '?1',
                '?2',
            ]))
            ->setParameter(1, 'ACTIVE')
            ->setParameter(2, 'ANOTHER')
            ->execute();
    return $result->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: `Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters` Получается, я не могу использовать этот способ совместно с именованными параметрами? Да и вообще вся прелесть in пропадает. Я просто хочу сделать ->in('state', [1,2,3,'ABC',false]) и получить результат. Почему-то это либо не работает так, как хочется, либо не удобно совершенно.

Comment: Использовал в in именованные параметры. Пока что это наименее костыльное решение из всех работавших.

Comment: @ilyaplot IN вообще всегда плохо работал в SQL-биндингах. Насколько понимаю, это ограничение со стороны prepared statement.

Comment: Я впервые сталкиваюсь с доктриной, раньше работал с yii 1.x и 2.x. Там вообще никогда не было проблем с in. Я просто передавал массив и он корректно передавался. Ожидал от доктрины примерно того-же, но был разочарован.